# Ambari Heartbeat Lost during Installation

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

​We are trying to install , HDP via Ambari 2.1.
The registration is succesfull, but during the install process, the ambari server (ambari-server.log) reports that it has lost an heart beat of the agent.

Error Message :
Heartbeat lost from host amabri.agent.com
The ambari-agent log reports:
Failed to connect to https://amabri-server.com:8440/connection_info due to [Errno 111] Connection refused
We are using openjdk 1.7 on RHEL 6.6 64 bit. 
Any pointer to the issue would help immensely ?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the *ambari-agent* on that particular host.